# NEO4J Relationship -> With categories and sub categories

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV with a lot of categories and sub categories and sub sub categories, I would like do that:
[image]

I had try with a second CSV, but he detect subcategories but not sub sub categories.

Comment: I think you need to show an example of data, and more clearly describe the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Fianally, I have found a solution:
Get 2 CSV on create relation with first CSV parent and s